# 'Cannot read properties of undefined' with React Testing library for decoding JWT token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, enzyme, react-testing-library

I'm fairly new to React testing library and am using a function within a useEffect to decode a user token from keycloak when they sign up, to determine what type of user they are and render different Menu's based on that. This new Jwt function I created though, is causing a lot of my previously working tests within other files to fail as it throws an error like below:

[image]

I'm sure how to deal with this error on the testing side, should I be mocking this decoder function within the test file?

This is my main file:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, useMemo, useCallback} from "react";
import {withTranslation} from "react-i18next";
import "./index.scss";
import {historyObject} from "historyObject";
import {Heading} from "@xriba/ui";
import { keycloak } from "utils/keycloak";

export const Menu = (props) => {
    const {t} = props;

    const [userHasCommunities, setUserHasCommunities] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {

        function parseJwt (token) {
            var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
            var base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
            var jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(window.atob(base64).split('').map(function(c) {
                return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
            }).join(''));

            if (JSON.parse(jsonPayload).communities?.length > 0){
                setUserHasCommunities(true)
            }

            return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
        };

        parseJwt(keycloak.token);
    
    }, [userHasCommunities])

    const buildItem = useCallback((item) => {
        const isCurrent = historyObject.location.pathname.includes(item.path);

        return <li key={item.path} className={isCurrent ? "selected" : ""} onClick={() => historyObject.push(item.path)}>
            <Heading level={"4"}>{t(item.title)}</Heading>
        </li>
    }, [t])

    const renderMenu = useMemo(() => {

        let menuItems = []
        if (userHasCommunities){
            menuItems = [
                {
                    path: "/portfolio",
                    title: "pages.portfolio.menu_entry"
                },
                {
                    path: "/transactions",
                    title: "pages.transactions.menu_entry"
                },
                {
                    path: "/community",
                    title: "pages.community.menu_entry"
                },
                {
                    path: "/reports",
                    title: "pages.reports.menu_entry"
                }
            ]
        } else {
            menuItems = [
                {
                    path: "/portfolio",
                    title: "pages.portfolio.menu_entry"
                },
                {
                    path: "/transactions",
                    title: "pages.transactions.menu_entry"
                },
                {
                    path: "/reports",
                    title: "pages.reports.menu_entry"
                }
            ]
        }
        return menuItems.map(i => buildItem(i))
    }, [userHasCommunities, buildItem])

    return <div className={"menu"}>
        <ul>
            {renderMenu}
        </ul>
    </div>
}
export default withTranslation()(Menu)
```

And my current test file:

```
import React from "react";
import {shallow} from "enzyme";
import {Menu} from "features/layouts/logged-in/menu/index";
import {historyObject} from "historyObject";
import { keycloak } from "utils/keycloak";
jest.mock("utils/keycloak");
jest.mock("historyObject")

describe("Menu test", () => {
    const props = {
        t: jest.fn(),
    };
    
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetAllMocks();
        jest.spyOn(React, "useEffect").mockImplementationOnce(x => x()).mockImplementationOnce(x => x()).mockImplementationOnce(x => x()).mockImplementationOnce(x => x());

    });


    it('should render Menu', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Menu {...props} />);
        expect(wrapper).toBeDefined();
        wrapper.find('li').at(0).prop('onClick')();
        expect(historyObject.push).toHaveBeenCalled()
    });
    it('should render Menu with an object as current', () => {
        historyObject.location.pathname = "/portfolio"
        const wrapper = shallow(<Menu {...props} />);
        expect(wrapper).toBeDefined();
        expect(wrapper.find('.selected')).toHaveLength(1);
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: It seems like `keycloak.token` variable is undefined while calling  parseJwt function in the useeffect in you main file. What might help you is wrapping your parseJwt function call in useeffect around an "if (keycloak.token)" which would only call the function once the value is defined.

Comment: @kavandalal Damn, I didn't even think about that but just added it and that's definitely helped with all other tests now passing. Thanks a lot!!